# Complex Analysis and Probability Theory

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, reference-request, soft-question

My question is a general one. I know that in complex analysis we find some very powerful theorems but given that my main area of study is Statistics and Probability, does complex analysis have applications in those areas? I know that it is helpful for example in the characteristic functions but do you think a deeper level of understanding can make a big difference? Will it make me a better Statistician? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are interested in resolution of singularities of varieties and applications of analytic functions in statistical modelling you could have a look at Watanabe's [Algebraic Geometry and Statistical Learning Theory](http://books.google.ch/books?vid=9780521864671&redir_esc=y). It is really a nice one.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a look.